# How to resolve "Cannot GET /" for webpack-dev-server in inline mode

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server

When I use webpack-dev-server (version 1.14.0) in inline mode and visit http://127.0.0.1:8080, the result is `Cannot GET /`.

[image: Error message screenshot]

The config in the `webpack.config.js` is:

```
devServer: {
    color: true,
    historyApiFallback: false,
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: assetsRoot
}
```

The npm scripts in the `package.json` are

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "clean": "node npm-scripts/del-build.script.js"
}
```

Comment: Which webpack version are you using?

Comment: webpack 1.14.0,

Answer (score 1):

use node server.js
the server.js code:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('../webpack.config');
console.log(config);
// 就是这么“复杂”！
// 往webpack的入口配置中加入 webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/ 即可
for (var i of Object.keys(config.entry)){
    config.entry[i].unshift("webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/");
}
console.log(config.entry);
var compiler = webpack(config);
var server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {

});
server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same question today and when I tried to search solutions, I saw this question.

Firstly I got 'Cannot Get /' on the webpage as you do, then I found that I mistake the contentBase path with"`path.join(__dirname,'/dist')`, lead to the server cannot find the page.

Then I solve this problem. In my webpack.config.js ,the devServer set should be:

```
`devServer: {` 
`contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/client/dist"),`
`compress: true,`
`hot:true,`
`port: 8888,`
`inline:true`
`}`
```

Maybe you can try this and check your directory again.